# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_finance'

Tags: python, mplfinance

Hi I am following a tutorial that was using matplotlib.finance to use candlestick.ohlc. When researching I found out that that lib was deprecated and to use mlp_finance. I believe I have installed it by running the command prompt and entering the line pip install mpl_finance. The result that I get this

[image]

I tried re running the script but I still get the error:

```
     from  mpl_finance   import candlestick_ohlc
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_finance'
```

I checked the python library path and I don't see a folder  labeled mlp_finance(Im not sure if Im suppose to). But I do see a file labeled mpl_finance-0.10.0-py3.7.egg

[image]

Any help on resolving this issue? Downloaded the git package and ran the command prompt install

[image]

ran the command line pip install git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance.git mpl_finance.git

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`pip install mlp_finance` will solve the issue

Comment: Should be `pip install mpl_finance` isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error you told, but I resolved it as below.

First, install mpl_finance

```
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip
```

Second, upgrade mpl_finance

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
```

Hope that this will work.

Comment: This is a very confusing answer.  `mpl_finance` and `mplfinance` are two different packages.  There is no reason to install both.  `mpl_finance` is the old deprecated version.  `mplfinance` is the new version.  They both **do the same thing but have a very different interface**.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#usage and https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#old-api-availability for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow that tutorial on mpl_finance, you can do so by installing the new mplfinance:

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
```

**Then** every place the tutorial tells you to import `from mpl_finance` change the import to
 `from mplfinance.original_flavor`, for example:

change:

```py
from  mpl_finance   import candlestick_ohlc
```

to

```py
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
```

Comment: oh damn, this is darn~~~sweet! problem solved perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2):

if you using Anaconda - To install this package with conda run:
conda install -c conda-forge mplfinance

Answer (score 0):

You need to install matplotlib/mpl_finance at https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance.git mpl_finance.git
cd mpl_finance.git
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Did what you sayed still not getting it posted the result in orig question. Still not getting it

Answer (score 0):

`mpl_finance` has been deprecated, just install the module as `mplfinance`.

Comment: why you changed depreciated to deprecated ? is there a thing called deprecated ?